# Best way to copy an Azure SQL Server database with encrypted columns from one subscription to another

Tags: sql, azure, copy, azure-sql-database

What is the best and easiest way to copy an Azure SQL Server database with encrypted columns from one subscription to another.

Tried to export to a `.bacpac` file but it errors with

> SQL71626 (certificate/symmetric key is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12)

Should I make a copy and then remove the keys before I export/import?

Comment: Hi RGI, Congratulations your question is answered. I help you post it as the answer. You can think about  (mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations your question is answered here:

[Copy SQL database with encryption from one Azure subscription to another](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/256699/copy-sql-database-with-encryption-from-one-azure-subscription-to-another).

I post it as the answer and this can be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 0):

SQLPackage.exe is used to export the database and it does not support symmetric keys. If you can [copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-copy?tabs=azure-powershell#copy-a-database-by-using-the-azure-portal) the database, then drop the symmetric key and the certificate on the database created by the copy operation. After that you will be able to export that copy of the database as a bacpac.